# How to implement IValidatableObject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-validation

I have 3 textboxes and main idea is if any of these fields are empty to get one error message but i dont know how to use this...any help?

```
[Required]
public int? Day { get; set; }

[Required]
public int? Month { get; set; }

[Required]
public int? Year { get; set; }

public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (Day == null || Month == null || Year == null)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope the following answer will help you.

**Inherit ValidationAttribute**

```
public class SingleMessageValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object obj)
    {
        DateValidation app = obj as DateValidation;
        if (app.Day == null || app.Month == null || app.Year == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "In valid date enter all fields";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
[SingleMessageValidation]
public class DateValidation
{
    public int? Day { get; set; }
    public int? Month { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model DateValidation

<h2>DateValidation</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @:Day: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Day)
    <br />
    @:Month: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Month)
    <br />
    @:Year: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Year)

    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
}
```

Comment: How can i call this validation in my view?

Comment: @None, I have updated the answer with view. Check it

Comment: is it possible to avoid this validationSummary because i want to use @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Birthdate) ... if u know what i mean? because i have more fields to validate and i want to display error message next to the field

Comment: @None, you can try Java script validation